# a subtitle vs subtitles

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the difference between saying *a* subtitle vs subtitles.
What would *a* subtitle refer to - one sentence or an entire subtitles?
For example, if I create a srt file for a movie, would that be a subtitle or subtitles?

Comment: A book or an article can have **a** subtitle; a film has subtitle**s**.

Comment: Have you looked up subtitle in [a dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subtitle)? Doesn't it explain this? "1. a secondary or explanatory title 2. a printed statement or fragment of dialogue appearing on the screen..."

Answer (score 1):

Question: [...] if I create a srt file for a movie, would that be a subtitle or subtitles?

The file contains the subtitles.

> An SRT file is a subtitle file that stores text which can be displayed
> along with video in a media player.

[live wire](https://www.lifewire.com/srt-file-4135479)

You created an SRT file that stores subtitles. or...
the SRT file with the subtitles

This movie has subtitles or is subtitled. The subtitles are stored in SRT format.

Answer (score -2):

If you are creating a single srt file the sentence would be

> I created a subtitle for this film

If you create 2 or more srt files the sentence would be

> I have created multiple subtitles for the this film

Comment: No one creates *a* subtitle for a film.  You do all of them or none, usually.. For one film, they are all in one SRT file.

Comment: You sometimes see "a subtitle" used for [an individual piece of text](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subtitle) shown on screen all at once, but if talking about the text for a whole film you absolutely want "subtitles".